# calculate how many months in a time period

Tags: typescript, date

I am trying to calculate how many months are there between two dates (both extremes are included). I have tried the following :

```
  var duration : moment.Duration;
  const contractStartMoment = moment(contractStart); //contractStart=01.05.2021
  const contractEndMoment = moment(contractEnd); //contractEnd=31.05.2021
  duration = moment.duration(contractEndMoment.diff(contractStartMoment));
  var months = duration.asMonths().valueOf();
  console.log('months' + ':' +  duration.asMonths()); //This prints : 0.9856465225158627
```

The expected value of `months` is 1 since it is a whole month but I am getting instead 0.9856465225158627. Could someone please correct me what I am missing here.

Comment: What is a month? Is it 30 days, 31? Is it measured an in an amount of seconds (probably what your code does)? It actually varies every month and even worse every 4 years. 

You need some kind of accurate definition of what a month is in your program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cursory hypothesis would be that it's taking into account the time of day that the contracts started and ended. For example, if both contract variables started at noon, then the duration would be 30 days. But the month, as evidenced by the end date, is 31 days. 30/31 is 0.9677 months. I'd hazard that unless the contract started on midnight on the 1st and ended 11:59:99 on the 31st, the `asMonths()` will return some fraction of a whole month.

There's also the factor that you can't cleanly convert 30 OR 31 days into months, since different months have different numbers of days. Looking at Moment.js' source code, what they do is `return (days * 4800) / 146097;`, which is 400 years of months divided by 400 years of days. This is to take into account all the leap year rules to come up with the best possible average of days in a month. Because of this, 31 days would actually be slightly MORE than the length of a month.